# How are the credentials kept safe during an OAuth flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm developing a full-stack app, let's called it X. When the user clicks 'sign in with your spotify account' link on X's frontend, a request is sent to the backend which fetches the `SpotifyAuthURL` from the backend. It's important to fetch the URL from the backend in order to avoid putting credentials like `client_id` and `redirect_url` in the frontend JS code.

Eventually, the fetched URL is opened in the browser through `window.location.href`. What I don't understand is what's the point of doing all this delicate manoeuvring when all the credentials are eventually going to be exposed in the query parameters of the URL in the address bar of the user's browser?